# Replace a printer with a pc using serial port

Tags: c, linux, shell, serial-port, parallel-port

### I have to update my question (May 4th). The male db25 connector misled me to the parallel port so I rephrased it.

I have an old computer system that sends live data (temperature from some external devices) to a parallel dot printer. This computer must not be changed.
Instead of printing I would like to connect the printer cable in an (ubuntu os) pc serial port in order to receive those data and redirecting them in stdout.

Checking the db25 pins I discovered that it is used as RS232 serial cable. There are only three pin connected:

- pin 2 (TXD)
- pin 3 (RXD)
- pin 7 (GND)

So my intentions are firstly to connect those pins to a db9 serial connector in order to plug it in a pc serial port and secondly to open and read the input data using:

```
chmod o+rw /dev/ttyS0
cat -v < /dev/ttyS0
```

I believe that it is a simple solution and it is going to work.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Reading+parallel+port+data+in+C `not locate an active dev file` - what do  you mean by that?

Comment: I mean that no device file is created when the 25-pin connector (or the usb) is plugged in a pc port. For example the event2 file in an ubuntu virtual machine I use in my laptop correspond to keyboard input.

Comment: Lpt port doesn't detect plugging, it's not plug&play device.

Comment: I see, but I am looking forward a way to read data from it. Is there another device file for parallel port? Or may I force the system to create it? (Firstly,I have to read your links which probably will give an answer, thank you!)

Comment: With a serial port you need to set up some parameters like speed and flow control.  You might try picocom.